# CakePHP webroot not accessible on new Apache setup

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, apache-config

I've just set up a new Ubuntu 10.4 slice on Slicehost, and have installed apache, mysql and php. I've uploaded my CakePHP app and everything is running fine, except for the webroot being inaccessible.  I have tried adding AllowOverride to all in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and followed the Cake instructions to httpd.conf by adding

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all</Directory>
```

However, this is still not redirecting properly.  I've hacked the css script tags to point to /app/webroot/css but would really like to know how to solve this issue properly.  Any help would be much appreciated, this is the first time for me to setup a new slice, so apologies for the noobish question

Comment: can you show us the relevant part of your /etc/apache2/sites-available/default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this sounds like mod_rewrite problem. Could you check if you enabled your mod_rewrite in apache configuration?

Comment: Solved this not long after posting, as you said it was simply that mod_rewrite was not enabled on Apache